# Django: Set initial value for ForiegnKey in a CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-1.9

I'm trying to create a view of type `CreateView`. This view will take the `form_class = CourseForm` that I created and excluded some fields in it. The `instructor` field is a foriegnKey and I don't want the user to be able to control it in the form. It's a field that depends on the signed in user.

```
# forms.py
class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        exclude = ['instructor', 'members', 'slug']
    # ...
```

my view is as follows. I thought that by including the instructor value in `initial` would pass the profile instance when I submit

```
# views.py

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class CourseCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'course_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('course-create-complete')

    form_class = CourseForm

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(CourseCreateView, self).get_initial()
        initial = initial.copy()
        profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=self.request.user)
        initial['instructor'] = profile
        return initial


# models.py

class Course(models.Model):
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="Instructor")
    # ... other fields
```

but the probelm is that whenever I submit the form I get the following error:

> NOT NULL constraint failed: myapp_course.instructor_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the initial value of `instructor` field, you shouldn't exclude it from the form. You could instead make the field hidden.

Or you could include that in the `exclude` list, but then you shouldn't override `get_initial` method, but do the assignment manually:

```
class CourseCreateView(CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        # create instructor based on self.request.user
        self.object.instructor = instructor
        self.object.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Check django doc about [what does `save(commit=False)` do.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Also check django doc about `form_valid` function and [how forms are handled in class based views.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#form-handling-with-class-based-views)

Comment: In this case, I think excluding is the better solution; otherwise you need to validate the user input. Your second solution is therefore much preferred.

Comment: ...however, I think you can rewrite it to set the instructor _before_ saving (and then just return `super(...)`).